# Disable/ Remove "Estimate Shipping and Tax" Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart

anyone care to advise on how to remove the "Estimate Shipping and Tax" option on Shopping Cart page ?

Answer (score 37):

In your local.xml file, add the following.  This should remove the block.

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    <remove name="checkout.cart.shipping" />
</checkout_cart_index>
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that Delphin's solution works, however, it isn't as "update friendly" as mine, as it expects you to have a copy of checkout.xml in your local theme, and this might change when you upgrade and you'll be missing the updates.

Comment: Thanks.  But where's this file located ?

Comment: /app/design/frontend/your_package/yourtheme/layout/local.xml

Comment: Thanks.  Would that be tempmela.xml in /app/design/frontend/default/MAG090172/layout

Comment: local.xml does not exist out of the box, you have to create it (it contains layout upgrades and obviously empty store doesn't have any).

Comment: Ok - i have created a local.xml file in folder public_html/app/design/frontend/default/MAG090172/layout >  Code: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<layout>
        
    <checkout_cart_index>
    <remove name="checkout.cart.shipping" />
    </checkout_cart_index>
 
</layout>                                                                   *** Unfortunatley it's not removed the block.  Is the file in correct folder ?   Is syntax fo code correct ?

Comment: Where do you suppose to put this? When I put the code at the end of the file - it completely destroys the layout of the page....

Comment: Create a `local.xml` file in `app/design/frontend/<yourpackage>/<yourtheme>/layout/` and then ensure it is before the closing `</layout>` tag.

Comment: @DouglasRadburn You mean app/etc/local.xml file right?

Comment: @zus no - this is related to a theme, not the Magento core application

Comment: @DouglasRadburn After added still showing, anything else i need to do?

Answer (score 7):

Check this and put in your theme's local.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<layout>
    <checkout_cart_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <remove name="checkout.cart.shipping"/>
        </reference>
    </checkout_cart_index>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 4):

Remove the following code from below file.

> app/design/frontend/your_package/yourtheme/layout/checkout.xml

```
<block type="checkout/cart_shipping" name="checkout.cart.shipping" as="shipping" template="checkout/cart/shipping.phtml"/>
```

Finally Clear the cache in the admin panel.

Comment: Never remove anything from layout xml file, jut do it in your local.xml file.