# Remove Estimate Shipping and Tax Form

Tags: shipping, forms

Bit of a Magento newb, I am working on version 1.9.1.1

I know the question has been asked before, I have tried all of which I can find, but none of them see to work for me.

I just want to remove the Estimate Shipping and Tax Form so it just displays the various shipping rates on the Cart page.

Been pulling my hair out with this for 2 days :(

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: You might want to look into this answer: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/28530/disable-remove-estimate-shipping-and-tax-magento-1-9