# How to remove the "Estimate your Freight" option?

Tags: estimate

How to remove the: "Estimate your Freight" option from the check-out process?

Magento 1.9.1.

I did a search for this and it says:

"Search Results for  remove estimated freight

Your search returned no matches."

Answer (score 0):

Go to app/design/frontend/yourpackage/youtheme/template/checkout/cart.phtml and and find the following line of code

```
<?php if (!$this->getIsVirtual()): echo $this->getChildHtml('shipping'); endif; ?>
```

Delete it or replace it with the following:

```
<?php //if (!$this->getIsVirtual()): echo $this->getChildHtml('shipping'); endif; ?>
```

Note, if your theme does not have the file, copy it from base/default into your theme and make the change. Don't make the changes to the base version or it could get overwritten in future updates.

Answer (score 0):

Quit destroying templates, block removals like this are a quick and easy fix through layouts.

Addressed here => [Disable/ Remove "Estimate Shipping and Tax" Magento 1.9](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/28530/disable-remove-estimate-shipping-and-tax-magento-1-9)

Quit destroying templates, template display text changes are often a quick and easy fix through the language translation table.

Addressed here => [Changing Magento template display text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23178625/722112)